# Get logged in user in Wildfly

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, authentication, wildfly, jaas

here's my problem:

I have a simple demo application with a jsf page and a bean. It runs on Wildfly 8.1. I would like to render several buttons on that page, depending on whether the user is logged in and on the roles that this user has.

I'd like to use the application-users.properties file for authentication, not a database and no LDAP, etc. But ideally I'd like to remain independent from the authentication method.

Being the newb that I am, there are several obstacles I cannot overcome at the moment. Those are:

1. How can I get the logged in user and his roles in my Bean? I was hoping for something like (pseudo code):

   ```
   @Inject
   HasMyUser hasMyUser
   ...
   User user = hasMyUser.getLoggedInUser();
   roles = user.getRoles();
   ```
2. Can I make Wildfly promt me for user credentials for the application realm? Much like it does when I try to access Wildfly's management console?
3. In case the former is not possible: how would I implement a simple login myself? Creating a jsf login form isn't the problem - but how would I validate the credentials against the content of the application-users.properties file?

Any help is much appreciated. Especially verbose help, as I have very little knowledge of authentication, Wildfly and webservers in general.

Sorry If I'm a little vague or if my approach seems somehow odd... If so, I'll gladly elaborate.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I now realize a problem with my approach / my understanding of security in Wildfly. I was quite surprised that I didn't find any simple solution to this common problem. The reason for that is that searched for authentication in Wildfly where I should have searched for authentication with JAAS which is included in wildfly. But there are other frameworks one can use, as well. I am currently looking into SHIRO. When I find something that works for me I will answer my own question. But that shouldn't keep anyone else from doing it either.

Comment: You can `@Inject javax.security.Principal myUser` to get the current authenticated user. You don't normally need to get the user's roles. Instead you test using [HttpServletRequest.html.isUserInRole("some_role"))](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole(java.lang.String)) to check if the user is in a specific role.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Steve, and sorry for responding (extremely) late. Stressful times. I use shiro now, and so far I'm very happy with it. But I'll try your suggestion, too.